# About exist two same name class in different jar?

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

In my current project I used `Guava Cache` to cache something with expiration, but when actually call this interface, it had below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J
    at com.google.common.base.Ticker$1.read(Ticker.java:64)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2225)
```

And the reason is that  there are two `Platform` in the classpath

[image]

one in `Gauva`, one in `google-collections:jar`

And `LocalCache` of Guava uses `Paltform` of `google-collections` causes this error. I have some question about this, why not Class in the same jar has higher priority? why not randomly choose one, but always use `Platform` of `google-collections`?

Comment: Check your imports. You might import the wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is possible that **two jars include the same class name**. It happens when you import for example two jars of different versions of the same library.

If you import dependencies using maven for example when you import a library it can import dependencies of other libraries causing this kind of problem. In this case you need to explicit that when you import a library you need to exclude a secondary dependency. This is done with the [exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can force priority by specifying classpath order. Java look for class in jars in order that is pecifyed in classpath.

In case you using maven and ide to run you have no control over order of classpath, but you can exclude dependee module from classpath.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some</groupId>
        <artifactId>id1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>another</groupId>
                <artifactId>id2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

In this case `id2` will not be in your classpath anymore.

Answer (score 0):

class loading priority will depends on the ClassLoader, you can find lot of articles about java class loading. if you are trying to run a standalone java application probably class loading will be done by URLClassLoader.

in this case all urls(jar file locations or classes) given in the -cp or -classpath will be added as URLs to the URLClassLoader, then when application needs to load a class this URLClassLoader will iterate through its URLs and once it found the class it will be loaded.

so everything depends on the class path order.

NOTE: but in some context class loading is not simple as this. ex: jboss-module class loader.